# PHP JSON - Array within an Object

Tags: php, json

I have the following JSON decoded.
I can access the notificationType as follows:

json->notificationType

I need to be able to access emailAddress deeper in the structure and I've tried the following unsuccessfully:

json->bounce->bouncedRecipients[0]->emailAddress

Any tips on access the emailAddress value?

thanks

```
stdClass Object
(

)
```

Comment: `json->bounce->bouncedRecipients[0]->emailAddress` looks fine - what errors are you getting

Comment: @somethinghere What on earth is wrong with an object! Converting a perfectly good object to arrays is totally unnecessary.

Comment: @somethinghere _RUBBISH_ What do you think this structure is for `{}` ... Well it defines an OBJECT when the JSON is a being passed as a string, between different languages

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thank you for being incredibly twitchy. It is an _opinion_ but sometimes it helps.

Comment: @somethinghere JSON stands for __JavaScript Object Notation__ Note the use of the word __OBJECT__

Comment: @RiggsFolly it is a data structure, the semantics don't matter. Did I tell you off for using an `StdObject`? Stop being pretentious.

Comment: @somethinghere Oh, thats interesting, why should you think I would need _telling off_ for using _I assume you mean_ `stdClass` Is there something wrong with using `stdClass`, I am interested as I use it a lot

Comment: @RiggsFolly you read completely past the word `pretentious`, no? Now instead of stroking your ego, how about getting on with your life? We all learn new things every day, so don't come here pretending that other people are inherently wrong because they do things differently.

Comment: Array or object use is **personal preference**, using one over the other **does not provide a solution** as they should work both. Please don't go on with this discussion. The OPs problem is not reproducable so I close-vote it.

Comment: Adam, did you actually intend to remove the data structure or was that a mistake